# login to replace logout code in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I was trying to apply this little code on my codeigniter page to see if the login is going to replace the logout if a user logged in, and vice versa. I tested it on welcome page that comes with codeigniter framework, but nothing happen. The only thin I see is `login` link. I tried to use tank auth as login library to make things easy, but whenever I login to the welcome page, again the login link shows up again, which is none sense.

here is the code I used to replace login/logout

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']!="")
```

`{
      echo("<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> ");`

``` echo($_SESSION['username']);
``// displays username
}
else
{
      echo("<a href='login.php'>Login</a> ");
}
?> ```

Comment: Codeigniter doesn't use PHP native sessions. If you're using Tank Auth, use `$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()`, otherwise use the Session class.

Comment: @Madmartigan Thanks for the great comments. Ok, I'm new to CI and no sure where to use the code you provided me... any idea?? should that be in the controller??

Comment: It should replace where you have `isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']!=""`

Comment: @Madmartigan. man, you are amazing. Thanks billion times. God bless you forever. I used your code and **Jamie's** as well and worked like a charm. thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your login script is not setting the $_SESSION properly.  Use Firebug to see if you have an active session.  I'd also use a method to check whether users are logged in:

Your login class:

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
   if($this->session->userdata('username'))
   {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Your view:

```
if($this->login->is_logged_in())
{
   echo anchor('logout','Logout');
}
else
{
   echo anchor('login','Login');
}
```

Comment: @Digitalsite: This is *example* code to help you understand your problem, you have to actually write the code yourself! Please read this entry in the User Guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: You need to instantiate your login model first. So either in your view's controller, or the view itself, use: `$this->load->model('login');'.  If you don't know how to create models, apart from advising you to read more about how [MVC structures work](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html), I'd just include the function I mentioned about into your controller. It will be directly accessible in your view.

Comment: @Jamie Thanks a lot for the great effort. I will check it out now and see what I can do. I've been trying resolving this issue for 2 continuous days without sleep because I must finish it ASAP. Thanks again

Comment: @Jamie. man, you are a lifesaver. Thanks zillions of times. it worked very well after trying for 2 days. now I can go to sleep. Thanks